# Should I index user-generated content (UGC) products on my website or not? Should I add them to the sitemap?

Tags: seo, wordpress, search-engine-indexing, sitemap, noindex

We are a marketplace and our users introduce their products on our website through seller panels. In other words, these contents are user-generated content (UGC).

Considering that the introduced products may have short and poor content, can we index these products or not? Can we also add the links of these products to the sitemap?